# What is the aux_ directory in Boost?

Tags: c++, boost

What is the purpose or meaning behind the `aux_` subdirectory in the boost libraries?

For example:

- `boost/parameter/aux_/`
- `boost/mpl/aux_/`
- `boost/local_function/aux_/`

Comment: For **aux**iliary code, perhaps?

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, what exactly does that mean in regards to Boost?

Comment: Lots of Boost functionality is implemented in templates, which -- as we know -- need their *definition* to be included in the header file. You cannot hide it in a linker library. But because portions of that template code are *auxiliary* to the actual API functionality, they are put into a subdirectory so they do not confuse the user. I'd translate it for you, but I don't know *your* native language, and I'm sure you have access to an English > Native dictionary the same as I do...

Comment: Too localized; unlikely to be of help for future readers.

Comment: @FinalContest: Why what? Is a question about "what does 'aux' mean?" really OT in your eyes?

Comment: Nope, it is good to understand what the code is trying to achieve. To me, it is a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hints.  I eventually did find a page on www.boost.org that mentions (just in passing!) the directory structure, and why there are different conventions.  Here is what it says:

> The organization of Boost library headers isn't entirely uniform, but most libraries follow a few patterns:
>
> - Some older libraries and most very small libraries place all public headers directly into boost/.
> - Most libraries' public headers live in a subdirectory of boost/, named after the library. For example, you'll find the Python library's def.hpp header in
>
>   ```
>   boost\python\def.hpp.
>   ```
> - Some libraries have an “aggregate header” in boost/ that #includes all of the library's other headers. For example, Boost.Python's aggregate header is
>
>   ```
>   boost\python.hpp.
>   ```
> - Most libraries place private headers in a subdirectory called detail/, or aux_/. Don't expect to find anything you can use in these directories.

Source:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

Answer (score 0):

What @DevSolar wrote:

> Lots of Boost functionality is implemented in templates, which -- as
>   we know -- need their definition to be included in the header file.
>   You cannot hide it in a linker library. But because portions of that
>   template code are auxiliary to the actual API functionality, they are
>   put into a subdirectory so they do not confuse the user.

It looks like several similar directory naming schemes are used in boost:

- detail
- impl
- aux_

From what I can see all 3 of these subdirectories serve the same purpose.  The naming just depends on the specific boost library.  If there is a more specific purpose to the different naming convention, please edit or submit another answer...I'm only guessing here!